# Can't reach a control from EditItemTemplate in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, edititemtemplate

I can't find the controls I want when trying to update my gridview. The controls are textboxes and a dropdownlist from an EditItemTemplate. However, if I try to find a label in ItemTemplate it works just fine. The problem seem to be that it "jumps out" of edit mode before I have a chance to get the controls.

Markup for my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowEditing="ProductGridView_RowEditing"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="ProductGridView_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="ProductGridView_RowUpdating"
    OnRowDeleting="ProductGridView_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="ProductGridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Family" SortExpression="Family.Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFamily" runat="server" OnInit="ddlFamily_Init">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFamily" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Family.Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the code-behind from my RowUpdating method. How do I reach the controls from the EditItemTemplate? Am I missing something really simple?

```
protected void ProductGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {            
        // Get the controls

        GridViewRow row = ProductGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label lblName = (row.FindControl("lblName") as Label); // Returns this label, from the row being edited, just fine
        TextBox txtName = (row.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox); // null
        TextBox txtQuantity = (row.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox); // null
        DropDownList ddlFamily = (row.FindControl("ddlFamily") as DropDownList); // null

        // More code to populate product etc.
    }

protected void ProductGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        ProductGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGridView(_productRepo.GetAll());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of commandfield, try using like

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkManageTitle" runat="server" Text="Manage Title" CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkManageTitle" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

rest seems to be fine.

For Updating, Call `OnRowUpdating="Gridview1_RowUpdating"` on html page and on CS page declare an event.

```
Protected Void Gridview1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Don't forget to call `CommandName="Update"` on a `LinkButton`

Comment: I have tried this with a slight alteration which is two linkbuttons in each template instead of one. Edit and Delete in the ItemTemplate and Update and Cancel in the EditItemTemplate. When I click Edit the gridviewrow goes to edit mode, but when clicking Update the RowEditing doesn't trigger. Thoughts? Delete a row and cancelling the edit works fine.

Comment: For updating: you have to call RowUpdating event of a grid view..see the bove edited code.

Comment: That's what I meant. I have done waht you meantion and it still doesn't work. I have `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` on my page due to an error I got which I couldn't solve in any other way. Do you think it have to do with that?

Comment: I solved the problem. I created a new web form with the above code and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void ProductGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{            
    // Get the controls
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ProductGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox tname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");

    // More code to populate product etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. However, I have this in my code already. Will add to my original post.

Comment: tname is still null. Can't find any controls from EditItemTemplate.

Comment: In the RowEditing set the gridview edit index. as follows
ProductGridView.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;

Comment: I have set the edit index as following: `ProductGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;`. The code you mentioned is not possible since GridViewEditEventArgs doesn't contain a Row property.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe?

```
protected void ProductGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e){
            Label lblName = (Label)ProductGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblName");
            TextBox txtName = (TextBox)ProductGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName"));
            TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)ProductGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtQuantity"); 
            DropDownList ddlFamily = (DropDownList)ProductGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlFamily"); 
}
```